# Parse Json in javascript for keys contains backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse the following freebase API in jQuery.

> https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=us%20president&filter=(all%20type:/people/person)&output=(/common/topic/image)

But I've a problem when I try to access **`/common/topic/image`** "mId" for image .

Can any body tell me what is the right way to access objects or arrays which containg `"/common/topic/image"` these type of keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=us%20president&filter=(all%20type:/people/person)&output=(/common/topic/image)", function (data) {
    var r = data.result; 
    // iterate each result   
    $.each(r, function (i, j) {
        var arr = j.output['/common/topic/image'];
        //iterate each arr['/common/topic/image']
        $.each(arr['/common/topic/image'], function (k, l) {
            console.log(l);
        });
    });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6MCKA/)

From your comments,

If you check your `json`, last **`result`** has no array called **`/common/topic/image`**.

*So when it tried to iterate, it failed[Unable to get the length]*.

So just add an condition to it like `if (arr['/common/topic/image']) {...}`. Now if it has empty element it will be skipped.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6MCKA/2/

Comment: Thanx Praveen Jeganathan.

Comment: @ARV I'm glad I was able to help, my friend.

Comment: hello  Praveen Jeganathan i am getting error that" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " in   $.each(arr['/common/topic/image'], function (index, image) {}

Comment: it is able to parse the image but giving me error in console due to this arr['/common/topic/image']. what would be the solution.

Comment: @ARV if you check the last result in json, there no array called `/common/topic/image`.  So when it tried to iterate, it failed.  So just add an condition to it like ` if (arr['/common/topic/image']) {...}`.  Now it has empty element it will be skipped.  Now check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6MCKA/2/.  Hope you understand.

Comment: thanx  Praveen Jeganathan. Now it is working fine. Thancx for your guidance.

Comment: @ARV Glad to hear from you :)

Answer (score 0):

If object key contain dots or slashes, you can access it in this way:

```
var o = {
 'some.key': 123,
 'another/key': 321
};

console.log(o['some.key'], o['another/key']);
```